# Lua variable variables

Tags: lua

I'm very new to Lua, I'm working with it on an io controller which has strict limits on script sizes so I need to work within these limits.

I have a number of relays which I am controlling (1-64). I need to switch off a relay when an event happens,  but the relay I'm switching off can change.
I have a variable that holds the relay number and I need to turn off this relay.

I can achieve this using  I statements:

```
if variable = 1 then
  io.relay1=0 //Turns off the relay
end
else if variable = 2 then
  io.relay2=0 //Turns off the relay
end
```

However, this will very quickly become a large script when repeated for the 64 relays. Is it possible to address the relay using the value of the variable as the relay name? Similar to the below:

```
io.relay{variable}=0 //Turns off the relay1/2/3/4/5 etc. depending on the value of variable
```

Alternatively, is there another way to keep the code compact?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
io["relay".. variable]=0
```

However, this creates a string every time.

If you can change how `io` works, a better solution would be to make `io.relay` a table and then simply do `io.relay[variable]=0`.

Comment: `relays["relay"..tostring(variable)] = 0` - if variable is a nil

Comment: Absolutely spot on, thank you for your help. The io module is off the shelf, I have no control over the naming or structure of the addressing. Your suggestion works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the string allocation issue that lhf's answer has, you could pre-generate a string table and index into that:

```
relay_names = {}
for k = 1,64 do
  relay_names[k] = "relay"..tostring(k)
end
```

Then setting the IO states would look something like this:

```
io[relay_names[1]] = 1
```